# GitHub API- Unable to Get Commit Status

Tags: python-3.x, github, github-api

I am trying to obtain the status of my commit. The GitHub API documentation states I need a 'ref', which can be a sha, branch, or tag name.

I am using the sha from the 'head' parameter of the response from the following get request.

r = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/5", headers=headers, proxies=proxy)

sha = r.json()['head']['sha']

Then, I am using the GitHub commit statuses API to get the commit statuses for a reference with the following request.

response = requests.get(f"https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits/{sha}/statuses", headers=headers, proxies=proxy)

The first request returns the sha, however the second get request returns an empty list []. It shouldn't be returning an empty list []. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I'm encountering the exact same issue. The combined status is always Pending, and the list of statuses is empty, even though the Github UI shows the checks properly for the same commit SHA.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely that the statuses you see in the GitHub UI are "checks" created by GitHub Apps.

See https://docs.github.com/en/rest/checks/runs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-check-runs-for-a-git-reference

I.e. `/repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits/{ref}/check-runs`